# Is storing files under a web server root unsafe if it is handled by PHP and blocked by the web server site configuration file?

Tags: php, file-upload, nginx

Say you have a website which takes file uploads of a certain type and places them in a subdirectory (let's call it "videos") in the web root.

I have heard from various sources that trusting uploaded files is never safe, because a payload can be uploaded and executed, **even if** you check the file extension. Ideally, you should check the whole file (which could slow down the system if the uploaded file is a huge video file).

So my question is - is it still unsafe with the following configuration?
You handle the upload with POST requests to a PHP script which checks the file extension and renames the file, then places the file in the subdir "videos".
Let's say the subdirectory "videos" is protected like this (nginx):

```
 location ~ /(videos/|admin-stuff|etc) { deny all; }
```

When the files are placed in the directory, they have `-rw-r--r--` permissions. If I understand correctly, the files cannot be accessed/executed by any means.
Is it still a vulnerability?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You handle the upload with POST requests to a PHP script which checks the file extension and renames the file

You should check the mime type. PHP have `mime_content_type` [function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) for that. Even if it's possible to fool the mime header and have some code on the metadata of the file, this raises the bar for exploiting your system.

> If I understand correctly, the files cannot be accessed/executed by any means.

Not really. They cannot be executed directly by the shell. Nothing stops any attacker to uploading a script named as `script.mp4` and somehow executing `bash the-new-name.mp4` later.

Or using a local file include (LFI) vulnerability and use `include videos/the-new-name.mp4` and running a code on the ID3 description field. You could remove metadata from the files, so even if an attacker sends a video with a shell embedded in metadata and includes it exploiting a LFI, it cannot execute.

Your Nginx settings are good.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the location in the file system hierarchy, there is no difference between `/videos`, and `/var/www/html/site/videos`, or the like. The issue is what permissions, i.e. the executable bit, the directory and files have, (which you mentioned), and also the user to which they are assigned, e.g., `www-admin`, `nginx`, etc.

Also, file uploads should be limited to specific file extensions, but you should check the [mime-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) to ensure they did not simply rename the file. Finally, the files should be scanned by an antivirus software such as [ClamAV](https://www.clamav.net).